# How to reset a field in child component from parent component - angular

Tags: angular

I am facing bit confusion to reset a field in child component from parent. I'm having a field in child component, when calling a function in parent component the child field should reset.
Child component:

```js
    @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <input type="text" placeholder="Type your name..." [formControl]="Name"/>

        `})
    export class ChildComponent {
      Name = new FormControl('');
    }
```

Parent component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-parent-app',
    template: `

        `})
    export class ParentComponent {
      resetName(){
      // Here I need to reset my child component field..
      }
    }
```

If any one have idea, could you please help me to understand..

Comment: You are using a formcontrol, then just use [reset](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#reset)

Comment: @AJT_82 both are different components right, so I how can we reset from parent component..

Comment: I looked a bit too fast at your code. So, how are these even related to each other, via routing or with child tag in parent? But anyway, your answer is here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Depending on the case... This can also help: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you access the child through its selector within the template you can set up a [@ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) to gain access to its class which would look like below for the following example, using its class for the type. Be sure to import `@Viewchild` and `ChildComponent`.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-parent-app',
    template: `
         <my-app #component-child></my-app>
        `})
    export class ParentComponent {

      @ViewChild('component-child') childComponent: ChildComponent;

      public resetName(): void
      {
        console.log(this.childComponent) // should see everything within the class.
        this.childComponent.name.reset(); // should reset the form in child component
      }
    }
```

Drop a comment if you face any trouble.

Comment: This also helpful.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869385/angular-how-to-reset-child-components